# Чтение данных из cmd и сохранение результатов выполнения в файл [и любого консольного приложения] (на pascal, lazarus)

Tags: pascal, cmd, lazarus

В **run.cmd** прописываю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все работает, логи записываются в файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема возникает, когда я пытаюсь запустить программу в которой очищается консоль...

Пример запуска через cmd:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль сначала очищается а затем выводится текст `hello world`

И вот я запускаю приложение и после очистки консоли программой test.exe, прога перестает читать данные из консоли

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как заставить прогу не обращать внимание на очистку консоли??

Репозиторий  github com/picus23/cmd_reader